# wordpress search is not working with multiple words

Tags: wordpress, search, search-multiple-words

I am using flat theme in one of my wordpress website. In this search is not working when I write multiple words like "issue tracker". For one word it is working fine like "issue" or "tracker". Code of searchform.php file is :

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'flat' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'flat' ); ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'flat' ); ?>" />
    </form>
```

and my search.php file is :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php flat_hook_search_before(); ?>
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'flat' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php flat_hook_search_top(); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php the_posts_pagination( array( 'prev_text' => __( '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>', 'flat' ), 'next_text' => __( '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>', 'flat' ) ) ); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

        <?php flat_hook_search_bottom(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php flat_hook_search_after(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Previously it was working on my local setup, but now it is not working on my live version.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a lot to rectify this issue but unable to figure it out. To correct my search, I have used custom SQL query and its working fine.

As I need a simple wordpress search for post titles and content which should work for multiple words. My code is as follows :

Put this in functions.php :

```
function custom_sql_for_search( ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $search_string = esc_sql($_GET['s']);


     $sql = "SELECT  * FROM {$wpdb->base_prefix}posts WHERE  

                (post_title LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR post_content LIKE '%".$search_string."%') 
                AND (post_status = 'publish')
                ORDER BY post_type DESC, post_date DESC";

                $query=$wpdb->get_results($sql);

                foreach ($query as $post) {
                        $result[$post->ID] = $post->ID;
                }

          return $result;
}
```

Now I modified my search.php code as follows :

```
<?php get_header(); 

flat_hook_search_before();

$search_result = custom_sql_for_search();

        ?>

           <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'flat' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>

        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php flat_hook_search_top();

            if ( count($search_result) > 0 ) { 
            foreach( $search_result as $post ) {

               $post = get_post($post->ID);
               setup_postdata($post); 

               get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 

            } 


        } else { 

            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
        }

        flat_hook_search_bottom();

  ?>
        </div>

<?php flat_hook_search_after();
      get_footer(); ?>
```

My search is working for multiple words after this. But I am facing a another bug here. When I search anything with special character, it is not working. It is not working with inverted commas, apostrophe etc.

Please help if anyone can rectify this.